# Starting Mongod And Mongo From Terminal

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to clarify a few things with `mongodb` in my `node project`

I have MongoDb installed and running fine on OSX Mavericks. I can create collections and query them after running mongo in my terminal.

What exactly is mongod doing when running it from the console?

When I run mongod it complains about needing a path to `data/db` 
so I run `mongod --dbpath data/db` and it installs a few files to my `db folder`
 Once I run it like this it ends with

```
[initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

I know this should be open and listening on a port. I cannot figure out why mine does not stay running. even though I clearly state the path to the `data/db` file.

I installed with with homebrew and the `db files` are stored at usr/local/var/mongodb

Am I supposed to `--dbpath` there or the `data/db` path I create in each node project?

```
UPDATE
```

I have also found that a homebrew installation will give you a mongod.conf file which sets up a different `--dbpath @ usr/local/var/mongodb` and it sets your mongodb server to come on at setup. Which is the reasons for errors when running mongod even when specifying a

```
--dbpath.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the `mongod` process will store db data to `/data/db` (not `data/db`), which is owned by root user.

If you really want to start mongod without arguments, create the directory :

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

Then you can run `mongod` without `--dbpath` argument.

```
sudo mongod
```

I would not recommmend this solution cause using sudo can be dangerous.
Personnaly, I got a `~/data/db` folder that I use for mongo process.

```
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

Comment: I have also found that a `homebrew installation` will give you a `mongod.conf` file which sets up a different `--dbpath @ usr/local/var/mongodb` and it sets your `mongodb server` to come on at setup. Which is the reasons for errors when running `mongod` even when specifying a `--dbpath`.